# Is it possible to run Modern UI Apps in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, modern-ui

It seems like a basic question, but is there a way to run Windows 8 (Modern Apps) in Windows 7 (without a VM, that seems like cheating)?

My hunch is that it would be possible with some sort of hack, as the code is written in the same .Net languages as many other programs.

The only issue would be intercepting the finger to corner gestures, but I am not sure how much is there really (is it just a location, or a special win API call).

Is there software that can do this, or options that need to be changed to make this work?

Comment: Why would one want to do this?

Comment: @CalebJares So that they can run many more programs without changing their operating system?

Comment: It IS possible. Many games in Windows 8 App Store were written in JavaScript and HTML and they run on any OS with a browser. Those apps are installed at `c:\program files\windowsapps\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible because Windows 7 just doesn't have the API or the technologies to parse through the files for an app.

Comment: I think at least Visual Studio can run the Apps, so it must me possible, but that is a far from minimal solution

Comment: It is possible to write an emulation layer but you'd probably be better off just writing your own OS since most of the implementation is proprietary and probably covered under copyright and patent laws.

Comment: @soandos No, Visual Studio can't run the Apps outside of Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without going to a lot of work to write an emulation layer, and even that may be not be possible for technical or legal reasons.

Windows Store Apps are written to the new WinRT API that only exists in Windows 8.  This API looks similar to .Net, but is very different under the hood.